# jQuery does not display page/div element until refreshed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, navigation

now here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
    <title>ESocial</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />

    <script src="javascript/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>


    <script src="esocial.js"></script>
    <link href="css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="javascript/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(event) {

     $("#datepicker").datepicker();

  });

  function function1(){

      document.getElementById("datepicker").blur();
      if(document.getElementById("ui-datepicker-div")!= null){
          document.getElementById("ui-datepicker-div").focus();

      }
       //alert("The button1 lost its focus"); 
  }     

  function function3(){
      setTimeout('window.KeyBoard.hideKeyBoard()',1000);
      //;
  }

</script>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#datepickerto").datepicker();


  });
  function function2(){

       document.getElementById("datepickerto").blur();
       if(document.getElementById("ui-datepicker-div") !=null)
           document.getElementById("ui-datepicker-div").focus();

  } 
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="login">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>ESocial</h1>
        <a href="#login" data-icon="" class="ui-btn-right" onclick="navigator.app.exitApp();return false;">Exit</a>
    </div><!-- header -->
    <form id="waplogin"  action="menu.html" >
            <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <div id="divleft">
                    <p class="plabel">Username</p>
                </div>
                <div id="divright">
                    <input style="width: 80%;" id="username"
                        name="username" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <div id="divleft">
                    <p class="plabel">Password</p>
                </div>
                <div id="divright">
                    <input style="width: 80%;" id="password"
                        name="password" type="password" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="divleftButton">

                <!-- <a class="submitbutton " onclick="" href="#menu">Register</a> -->
                <a class="bluebutton" href="#registration" onclick="">Register</a>

            </div>
            <div id="divrightButton">


                <!-- The white class uses the 29x30 whiteButton PNG image to build the iPhone button -->
                <a class="bluebutton" href="#menu" onclick="loginSubmit(); return false;">Login</a>

            </div>
        </form>
</div>  

<!-- Registration Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="registration">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <a href="#login" data-icon="back">Back</a>
            <h1>Register</h1>
            <!-- <a href="#" data-icon="check" onclick="submitLeave(); return false;">Save</a> -->
        </div>
            <form id="registration" action="">
            <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <div id="divleft">
                    <p class="plabel">First Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="divright">
                    <input style="width: 90%;" id="firstName"
                        name="firstName" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <div id="divleft">
                    <p class="plabel">Last Name</p>
                </div>
                <div id="divright">
                    <input style="width: 90%;" id="lastName"
                        name="lastName" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <div id="divleft">
                    <p class="plabel">Email Id</p>
                </div>
                <div id="divright">
                    <input style="width: 90%;" id="emailId"
                        name="emailId" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <div id="divleft">
                    <p class="plabel">Mobile No.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="divright">
                    <input style="width: 90%;" id="mobileNo"
                        name="mobileNo" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <div id="divleft">
                    <p class="plabel">Password</p>
                </div>
                <div id="divright">
                    <input style="width: 90%;" id="registrationPass"
                        name="registrationPass" type="password" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <div id="divleft">
                    <p class="plabel">Confirm Password</p>
                </div>
                <div id="divright">
                    <input style="width: 90%;" id="confPass"
                        name="confPass" type="password" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <div id="divleft">
                    <p class="plabel">Date of Birth</p>
                </div>
                <div id="divright">
                    <input style="width: 90%;" id="dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth" type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <div id="divleft">
                    <p class="plabel">Gender</p>
                </div>
                <div id="divright">
                    <select style="width: 90%;" name="gender" id="gender">
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>



            <!-- submit button of registration -->
            <div id="divsubmitbutton">
                <br> <a class="submitbutton ui-link"
                    onclick="register(); return false;" href="#menu">Submit</a>
            </div>
        </form>
</div>

<!-- Main Menu -->
<div data-role="page" id="mainMenu">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <!-- <a href="#login" data-icon="back">Back</a> -->
            <h1>Main Menu</h1>
            <!-- <a href="#" data-icon="check" onclick="submitLeave(); return false;">Save</a> -->
            <a href="#login" data-icon="logout" class="ui-btn-right" onclick="navigator.app.exitApp();return false;">Logout</a>
    </div>
     Main menu
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Problem
a) when click on register, it loads the registration page, but nothing is displayed, untill i refresh and then i can see the page content and yes the URL on browser changes to(/login.html#registration)

same is when i try to load main menu

b)cannot see any data icons in the is set, even though data icon property

c)how to show page via jquery, please dont specify change div style to inline or display none, i need something else. for eg.. i called a method in scripts and that should hide a page and display based on my response from server

also, i am new to jquery/javascript development, so also tell everything step by step

Comment: it's a wall of code... could you reduce it and post only the relevant part?

Comment: you are mixing raw js with jquery methods and a div has no focus or blur event.

Comment: @f.calderan : should i repost or should i post back in another comment?? i am stuck for over a week on this problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all i came to know, that it was one some issue with firefox, the following code works fine in Google Chrome

`$.mobile.changePage("#mainMenu",{allowSamePageTransition: true });`

also the following  css file and yes it is a must, if you wish to load elements of same page

[jquery.mobile.transitions.css](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/ca9df1197a9748ee7448fb9b28c14c41d80d4601/themes/default/jquery.mobile.transitions.css)